# How to find the equilibria of this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$x' = x^2 + \mu$$
>
> Draw the graph for $\mu = 1$, $\mu = 0$,and $\mu = −1$.

I can draw the graph for this equation, which turns out to be like this:

[image]

But how do I find the equilibria of this particular differential equation? Or maybe how can I find equilibria of any equation?

Comment: @Moo Yes, it did

Answer (score 0):

One kind of equilibrium is about the motion of some particle in a potential field
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{grad}{grad}
m \ddot{x} = - \grad V(x)
$$
The shape of the potential field $V(x)$ may have points where the particle would rest. Depending on the neighbourhood it could be a stable equilibrium or not. (Think of a marble in a concave spot vs a marble on a convex top).

Maybe your task goes into that direction.

For this you need to explain what is meant by the $x'$ term.
Is it the derivative regarding to some variable?

Your graph shows the points $(x, x')$ where $x' = x^2 + \mu$.

Comment: Yeah x′ is the derivative.

Comment: $x' = dx/dx$? $x'= dx/dt$? .. What variable does $x$ depend on and is used to take the derivative?